# Statement in "except" tag not working in python

Tags: python

I have written the following code to save an album from a website.

```
import urllib2
import webbrowser
import os
page=1564848
fileno=1
for fileno in range(1,24):
    pages=str(page)
    filenos=str(fileno)
    picture_page = "url-to-the-website"+pages+".jpg"
    page=page+1
    os.chdir("/home/comrider/Album/")
    if not os.path.exists("3"):
        os.makedirs("3")
    os.chdir("/home/user/Album/3")
    try:
        opener1 = urllib2.build_opener()
        page1 = opener1.open(picture_page)
        my_picture = page1.read()
        filename = filenos + picture_page[-4:]
        fileno=fileno+1
        fout = open(filename, "wb")
        fout.write(my_picture)
        fout.close()
    except:
        fileno=fileno-1 #This statement is not working
        pass
```

Since there are missing image number i have given a try and except statement and in the except statement I have given a statement to decrement the file no. that was incremented in the try statements. But that code is not working resulting in incomplete downloading of the album. The working platform is linux. Please help. thanks in advance.

Comment: How can `fileno` can be automatically reset? There is no code segment to reset it.

Comment: in general a catch-all `except` is a bad idea. you should catch exactly the exception you are expecting - in this case `IOError` will be raised if the file does not exist. Also you should put the minimum amount of code possible in the `try` clause - you can use `else` and `finally` blocks to refactor. finally the `pass` statement at the end of your code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fileno` will be reset on the next loop iteration, you can change it to whatever you want but when the current for loop iteration ends it will increment from `1..24`

[from the docs:](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)

> Python’s for statement iterates over the items of any sequence (a list
>   or a string), in the order that they appear in the sequence

[`range`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a list sequence you are progressing along that sequence

if you need to mess with your counter you could use a while loop

```
fileno = 1    
while fileno < 24:
  #  do stuff
  # just remember to increment at the end, you control when the loop returns
  fileno += 1
```

Comment: ok... `while` solved the problem. I replaced the for with the `while` as you told and removed the line that didn't work. Now the code works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Information given in the previous answer is true, but can be stated less opaquely, as follows:  The statement
`for fileno in range(1,24):`
on successive executions will produce the sequence `fileno=1`, `fileno=2`, `fileno=3`, ... `fileno=23`.  It will do so regardless of what you do to `fileno` before the loop or within the loop.  As a consequence, it is pointless to set `fileno=1` before the loop, or to set `fileno=fileno-1` at the end of the loop.  I suggest that you remove those lines and also the `fileno=fileno+1` line from your program.  (Using a while loop is also a possibility, but is more verbose.)

On another issue, change

```
    fout = open(filename, "wb")
    fout.write(my_picture)
    fout.close()
```

to

```
    with open(filename, "wb") as fout:
        fout.write(my_picture)
```

That will properly open fout, write to it, and close it, as explained in [documentation](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) of the [with-statement](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).